# Pyspark streaming how to restructure JSON File

Tags: python, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

this is my input data stream for kafka i want to restructure in **pyspark streaming** to be in a JSON format link the one in the output .

**input stream:**

```
    {"name": "position_y", "value": "1.9", "timestamp": 1699258974900 , "type": "oxygen"},
    {"name": "position_y", "value": "1.9", "timestamp": 1699258974900 , "type": "temp"},
    {"name": "position_H", "value": "3.6", "timestamp": 1699258974900 , "type": "oxygen"},
    {"name": "position_x", "value": "5.1", "timestamp": 169925900 , "type": "oxygen"},
    {"name": "position_z", "value": "3.999", "timestamp": 169925900 , "type": "temp"},
    {"name": "position_x", "value": "5.1", "timestamp": 169925900 , "type": "temp"}
```

**output stream:**

this is the output restructure that i want

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": 1699258974900,
    "oxygen": {
      "position_y": "1.9",
      "position_H": "3.6"
    },
    "temp": {
      "position_y": "1.9"
    }
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 169925900,
    "oxygen": {
      "position_x": "5.1"
    },
    "temp": {
      "position_z": "3.999",
      "position_x": "5.1"
    }
  }
]
```

**here is my code that i use i am reading a stream form kafka that  consume the data as JSON format **

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, collect_list, struct
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()


df = (
    spark.readStream.format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "broker:29092")
    .option("subscribe", "testing")
    .load()
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")  
    .select("value")
)

# Define the schema for the JSON data
json_schema = "name STRING, value STRING, timestamp LONG, type STRING"
df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
df = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda x: x.value), schema=json_schema)


result = (
    df.groupBy("timestamp", "type")
    .pivot("type")
    .agg(collect_list(struct(col("name"), col("value"))).alias("data"))
    .groupBy("timestamp")
    .agg(
        struct(
            col("timestamp"),
            col("oxygen").alias("oxygen"),
            col("temp").alias("temp")
        ).alias("result")
    )
    .select("result.*")
)


output_query = (
    result.writeStream
    .outputMode("update")
    .format("console") 
    .start()
)
output_query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: what did you try? where is your code?

Comment: it seems you need first `.groupby("timestamp")` and later format data.

Comment: @furas here is my code